# Using PostBackUrl, Getting PreviousPage.Control()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using PostBackUrl to post my control from a "firstwebpage.aspx" to a "secondwebpage.aspx" so that I would be able to generate some configuration files.

I do understand that I can make use of **PreviousPage.FindControl("myControlId")** method in my secondwebpage.aspx to get my control from "firstwebpage.aspx"and hence grab my data and it worked.

However, it seems that this method does not work on controls which I generated programmically during runtime while populating them in a table in my firstwebpage.aspx.

I also tried using this function **Response.Write("--" + Request["TextBox1"].ToString() + "--");**
And although this statement do printout the text in the textfield on TextBox1, it only return me the string value of textbox1. I am unable to cast it to a textbox control in the following format too

**TextBox temptextBox = (TextBox)Request["TextBox1"];**

My question is, how can I actually access the control which i generated **programmically** in "firstwebpage.aspx" on "secondwebpage.aspx"?

Please advice! 
thanks alot!

//my panel and button in aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Generate Xml" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

//this is my function to insert a line into the panel

```
 public void createfilerow(string b, string path, bool x86check, bool x86enable, bool x64check, bool x64enable)
        {
            Label blank4 = new Label();
            blank4.ID = "blank4";
            blank4.Text = "";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(blank4);

            CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
            c.Text = b.Replace(path, "");
            c.Checked = true;
            c.ID = "1a";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(c);

            CheckBox d = new CheckBox();
            d.Checked = x86check;
            d.Enabled = x86enable;
            d.ID = "1b";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(d);

            CheckBox e = new CheckBox();            
            e.Checked = x64check;
            e.Enabled = x64enable;
            e.ID = "1c";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(e);
    }

//my virtual path in WebForm2.aspx

<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/WebForm1.aspx"  %>
```

//my pageload handler

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        CheckBox tempCheckbox = (CheckBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("1a");
        Button1.Text = tempCheckbox.Text;
    }         
}
```

//handler which will populate the panel upon clicking

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get foldername 

            if (!Directory.Exists(@"myfilepath" + TextBox2.Text))
            {
                //folder does not exist
                //do required actions
                return;
            }
            string[] x86files = null;
            string[] x64files = null;
            string[] x86filespath = null;
            string[] x64filespath = null;
            ArrayList common = new ArrayList();
            if (Directory.Exists(@"myfilepath" + TextBox2.Text + "\\x86"))
                x86files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("myfilepath" + TextBox2.Text + "\\x86");
            if (Directory.Exists(@"myfilepath" + TextBox2.Text + "\\x64"))
                x64files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("myfilepath" + TextBox2.Text + "\\x64");

            //some codes to convert x64files and x86files to string[]

            //The header for Panel, 4 column
            Label FL = new Label();
            FL.ID = "flavourid";
            FL.Text = "Flavour";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(FL);

            Label filetext = new Label();
            filetext.ID = "filenamelabel";
            filetext.Text = "File(s)";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(filetext);

            Label label86 = new Label();
            label86.ID = "label86";
            label86.Text = "x86";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(label86);

            Label label64 = new Label();
            label64.ID = "label64";
            label64.Text = "x64";
            Panel2.Controls.Add(label64);


            //a for loop determine number of times codes have to be run
            for (int a = 0; a < num; a++)
            {
                ArrayList location = new ArrayList();
                if (//this iteration had to be run)
                {
                    string path = null;
                    switch (//id of this iteration)
                    {
                     case id:
                     path = some network address
                    }

                    //check the current version of iternation
                    string version = //version type;
                    //get the platform of the version
                    string platform = //platform

                    if (curent version = certain type)
                    {   
                        //do what is required.
                        //build a list
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //normal routine
                        //do what is required
                        //build a list
                    }

                    //populating the panel with data from list

                        createflavourheader(a);
                        //create dynamic checkboxes according to the list

                     foreach(string s in list)
                     //createrow parameter is by version type and platform
                             createfilerow(readin, path, true, true, false, false);

                    }
                }
            }
            form1.Controls.Add(Panel2);
        }
```

Sorry can't show you the full code as it is long and I believe it should be confidential even though i wrote them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access, Below is an example

```
 // On Page1.aspx I have a button for postback
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
     PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />

 // Page1.aspx.cs 
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    TextBox t = new TextBox(); // created a TextBox
    t.ID = "myTextBox";        // assigned an ID
    form1.Controls.Add(t);     // Add to form

}
```

Now on the second page I will get the value of TextBox as

```
 // Page2.aspx.cs
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {       
    if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox) PreviousPage.FindControl("myTextBox");
        string mytboxvalue = t.Text;
    }
                        // OR
    string myTextBoxValue = Request.Form["myTextBox"];
 }
```

**Updated Answer:**

```
  Panel myPanel = new Panel();
    myPanel.ID = "myPanel";

    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.ID = "myTextBox";
    myPanel.Controls.Add(t);

    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
    t1.ID = "myTextBox1";
    myPanel.Controls.Add(t1);

    // Add all your child controls to your panel and at the end add your panel to your form
    form1.Controls.Add(myPanel);

   // on the processing page you can get the values as
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox) PreviousPage.FindControl("myTextBox");
        string mytboxvalue = t.Text;
    }

    string myTextBoxValue = Request.Form["myTextBox1"];
  }
```

Comment: I see, But as I had to add these control to a table in a regulated format, will adding "form1.Controls.Add(t)" will make my Checkboxes appearing twice in webpage. I would like to had a control of where i can add them in the page?

Comment: why twice ? you can use a panel control.

Comment: Because I added my checkboxes to a regular table. maintaining a structure friendly for user. So by what you mean, I can actually do something like form1.Panel1.Add(myCheckbox); , and at the same time, maintain the structure I will required?

Comment: I tried your method adding the control directly to the form. but it doesn't work too. I still have got a null exception while trying to retrieve the control.

Comment: panel is also dynamic or it is already present on your form ? if it is dynamic then first add your control inside panel controls as panel.controls.add(childcontrols) and at the end add your panel control to your form as form1.controls.add(panel)

Comment: I'm still getting a null exception
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.



Line 26:             {
Line 27:                 **CheckBox tempCheckbox = (CheckBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("1a");**
Line 28:                 Button1.Text = tempCheckbox.Text;
Line 29:             }

I wonder what is wrong. I had set my virtual path as well. Previous Page is not null. but my dynamic controls are not passed over :/

Comment: @user1594987 can you please share your code, se we can analysis it.

Comment: @user1594987 share the code of both pages. Edit your question and post your code there.

Comment: I can get all my control defined in WebForm1.aspx with no issue. It's just the dynamic ones.

Comment: @user1594987 ok. can you please share your dynamic code ? In my answer I showed that dynamic control can also be accessed.

Comment: The additional controls are actually added to the forms by createfilerow() the trigger is by button7_click. how many times it should add to the panels depends on userinput, but i set my test cases that it only trigger createfilerow once and i tried to grab checkbox whose id = "1a"

Comment: I'm not sure if it is because my dynamic controls are not added to the form correctly. because it is only the fixed controls are being read at page 2.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried using this function Response.Write("--" +
>   Request["TextBox1"].ToString() + "--"); And although this statement do
>   printout the text in the textfield on TextBox1, it only return me the
>   string value of textbox1. I am unable to cast it to a textbox control
>   in the following format too
>   TextBox temptextBox = (TextBox)Request["TextBox1"];

Hi lw,
I think you may try passing the type of control (e.g. 'tb') together with the content and creating a new object (e.g. TextBox) and assign it to templtexBox object.

My 20 cents.
Andy